# Cant see the data that inserted into table

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I connected my SQL database whith linq to sql, then I created an insert query and called `InsertOnSubmit()` and `SubmitChanges()`, it seems to be fine but that I can't see the inserted data, the table is still empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        t_pupilid addRow = new t_pupilid();
        int Num = db.t_pupilids.AsQueryable().Count();
        if (Num == 0 )
            addRow.pupId = 1;
        else
        {
            var query =
             from trc in db.t_pupilids
             select trc.pupId;
            addRow.pupId = query.Max() + 1;

            db.t_pupilids.InsertOnSubmit(addRow);
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table is empty your code goes into

```
      if (Num == 0 )
        addRow.pupId = 1;
```

but you are missing a `db.t_pupilids.InsertOnSubmit(addRow);` there.